# How to check value return from one query exist on a cursor in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

i have a cursor like this

```
cursor samp_emp is 
select distinct name
from employee;
```

i want to check if

> 'john'

exist on a cursor .is there are any inbuild function exist to check if value exist on the cursor?

Comment: A cursor is a specification for selecting data, not a container for results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without loop through cursor is there anyway of checking if the value exist on the cursor?

No, if you want to check if a value exists in a cursor then you will need to open the cursor and loop through all the values until either it is found or you have processed all the rows.

> is there are any inbuilt function to check if value exist on a cursor that loop through cursor and check?

No

Comment: is there are any inbuilt function to check if value exist on a cursor that loop through cursor and check?

Comment: @Optimuskck Updated